# org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj missing in Eclipse Neon release?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I updated my Eclipse target definition from Mars to Neon:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon

Now my launch is missing the `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj` bundle.
In Mars `Equinox Target Components` provided the bundle, but Neon does not.
What feature do I have to choose to get it back? Maybe even another update site?

EDIT: Also the Mars `Equinox Weaving SDK` feature contained the bundle, but this feature is not available in the Neon update site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update site contains the `Equinox Weaving SDK`:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/45/dev/update/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse bug [470000](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470000) seems to be the discussion of this. It seems like the AspectJ parts of the code have been moved to the Eclipse AJDT project and are no longer included in the Neon version of the Eclipse Weaving SDK.

The bug mentions some AJDT update sites.